# require file that uses also require

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I wrote a jQuery plugin and using **require.js** for it. My **plugin.js** file looks like this:

```
require(['path/to/something'], function(Something) {
    // LINE 1 <--------
    jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function(elem) {
        var s = new Something(elem);
        elem.data('something', s);
        return elem;
    };
});
```

In **index.html** I have:

```
   require(['js/plugin'], function() {
        $(function() {
            // LINE 2 <--------
            $('#elem').myPlugin();
        });
    });
```

When I am running the code, Line 2 runs before Line 1 and therefore exception is thrown:

> myPlugin is not a function.

Why Line 2 runs before Line 1? How can I fix this?

Comment: Should you be using `define` instead of `require` in your plugin.js? It seems like you've got an unnecessary layer here. If the module is a jQuery plugin, it should attach to the jQuery object within its definition function rather than requiring its own code.

Comment: @metadept: I am trying to separate between the plugin code and the website usage code. I can't put jQuery.fn.myPlugin = func... inside index.html. Later I'll use require.js optimization (http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) in order to convert all the plugin files to one file. More then that, I don't need define in plugin.js because I have nothing to return

Comment: Agree with @metadept. Shouldn't your module begin with `define` and have a dependency on `jquery`?

Comment: @PaulGrime: When I use define, after combining the require.js files using almond, the module is not loaded..